# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.2, laravel-6

I get this error in the browser on my test Laravel project:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
(SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = test@test.com)
```

I have found similar problems in Stack Overflow and other sites, but all the solutions given never worked for me.

Another similar error code refers to MySQL, but mine is about Laravel. Not MySQL. 
I use [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) (Bionic Beaver), Laravel 6, LAMP, my database is MySQL, the server is served by Apache 2.4, not Homebrew or PHP localhost.

----------(test project context)

I'm following a tutorial and I successfully added the LOGIN and REGISTER button. Now when I try to register a new user, I got two permission issues which I was able to solve with `sudo chmod`, but I have been stuck on this third problem for five hours now. I'm going to reinstall everything if I don't get this right by today.

In my understanding `PHP ARTISAN UI:AUTH` takes care of all the code and you only need to `PHP ARTISAN MIGRATE` after creating the authorization UI which I already did. I can actually see the tables `MIGRATE` created in database in the MYSQL terminal.

----------(/test project context)

Solutions I've tried:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.11 or localhost
DB_PORT=3306 or 33060
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root or I_created_a_new_user_with_all_privileges
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

I've tried matching my database configuration in the *app\config\database.php* file in Laravel.

I already `sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/blog` out of desperation.

I tried a bunch of clears in the terminal.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

This is *app\config\database.php* file:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),  <--- NEVER TRIED THIS PART THOUGH, idk what to put
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'), <---- tried all
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),      <---- tried 33060
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'), <--- tried 'test' as my DB
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'), <--- tried 'root' or 'nico'
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''), <--- 'password'
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',      <--- tried 'utf8'
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

I already checked the owners of the file and the programs. It's either *root* or *www-data* and made sure that Apache2 is ran by *root* or *www-data* either or both. I used `ps aux | grep apache`.

I never had this problem in Windows 10 WAMP stack. I'm at my wits end.

I recreated the project from scratch, but I still get the same error.

This article solved it: *[#1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' mysql -5.7 and ubuntu-16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998920/1698-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-mysql-5-7-and-ubuntu-16-04)*

```
Step 1. `sudo mysql -u root -p`

Step 2. `USE mysql;`

Step 3. `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'admin';`

Here 'admin' is your new password, but you can change it.

Step 4. Exit Thanks. You are done.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this soution !

```
    sudo mysql -u root -p
    > use mysql;
    > select user,host,plugin from mysql.user;
    > ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
    > flush privileges;
```

Comment: explain a bit, I am curious

Answer (score 1):

Try double-quote your password ( "password"). Sometimes it works.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should change the file .env

```
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

with values as in config/database.php

Comment: Maybe or definitely?

Answer (score 0):

I use double quotes on my password and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to install xampp and use mariadb from there, it works perfectly for me.

use el traductor para escribir lo de arriba xd

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).